# paramiko is installed but mysql workbench saying "ImportError: No module named paramiko"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

When i tried to open mysql workbench then it saying "ImportError: No module named paramiko; Operation failed: Cannot start SSH tunnel manager" although i have installed paramiko.
I am using python 2.7.3 
ubuntu 12.04

I am getting this error after trying to upgrade from python  2.7.3 to python 3 again i installed python2.7.5 but my gedit not working then coming back to python 2.7.3.
Now everything became normal except mysql work bench.
I am using workbench version 6.0

error report:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 30, in

```
import paramiko
```

ImportError: No module named paramiko

Operation failed: Cannot start SSH tunnel manager

Comment: In Python interpreter what does `help('modules')` say? Does it contain paramiko?

Comment: I suggest reinstalling `paramiko`, as this rewrites the files, adds your module in the path correctly and lots of other stuff, etc etc. Try installing again once? You can just go to existing paramiko and call `python2.7.3 setup.py install`. Let us know whether it works.

Comment: my paramiko is installed perfectly in the location /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko
but again i am getting the above error. I am really frustrated. Please help.

Comment: @milo when i trying help("paramiko") then it saying "no Python documentation found for 'paramiko'
".
What should i do now ?. Please help.

my paramiko is installed perfectly in the location /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko

Comment: You probably have multiple instances of Python and you don't use the appropriate one. If not, then reinstall paramiko no matter how certain you are about your current install.

Comment: yes , i have two separate instance of python2.7.3. 
1) /var/lib/python2.7.3 and 
2)/var/local/lib/python2.7.3
What i did then , just rename the one under local folder and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a virtual environment and to install `paramiko` in it.

```
virtualenv test
source test/bin/activate
pip install paramiko
mysql-workbench
```

For some reason it solved the problem for me, after `sudo apt-get install python-paramiko` and `sudo pip install paramiko` both failed. I also tried installing `paramiko` in a `conda` environment, and it failed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu 14.04:

- Ensure you have python-pip install

  pip install paramiko